# Binding in generic control is null

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have several generic buttons. Both title and the corresponding icon are displayed correctly, but the tap function does not work.

**HomePage.xaml with the ScanningApp control**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="primetals.ScannerApp.Views.HomePage"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:primetals.ScannerApp.Controls"
             xmlns:resource="clr-namespace:primetals.ScannerApp"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             BackgroundColor="White"
             x:Name="self"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="controls:ScanningApp">
                <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="220"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="220"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid Margin="10">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="3*"></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="backgroundImageRow" Height="4*"></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Margin="0,10,0,10">
            <!-- Application Logo -->
            <Image Source="icon_scannerapp.png" WidthRequest="96" HeightRequest="96"></Image>

            <!-- Welcome Text -->
            <Label Text="{x:Static resource:ApplicationResources.WelcomeMessageLine1}" FontSize="Large">
            </Label>
            <Label FontSize="Large">
                <Label.FormattedText>
                    <FormattedString>
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resource:ApplicationResources.WelcomeMessageLine2}"></Span>
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resource:ApplicationResources.WelcomeMessageSpareParts}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large"></Span>
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resource:ApplicationResources.WelcomeMessageOr}"></Span>
                        <Span Text="{x:Static resource:ApplicationResources.WelcomeMessageSensorData}" FontAttributes="Bold"  FontSize="Large"></Span>
                        <Span Text="!"></Span>
                    </FormattedString>
                </Label.FormattedText>
            </Label>
        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Scanning Applications -->
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Apps}" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Start">
            <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <controls:ScanningApp Margin="0,0,5,0"
                        ImageSource="{Binding ImageUrl}"
                        TapImageSource="{Binding TapImageUrl}"
                        Text="{Binding Title}"
                        TappedCommand="{Binding BindingContext.AppTappedCommand, Source={x:Reference self}}"
                        TappedCommandParameter="{Binding}">
                    </controls:ScanningApp>
                </DataTemplate>
            </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>

        </StackLayout>

        <!-- Background Image -->
        <Image x:Name="backgroundImage" Grid.Row="2" Source="background_scannerapp_PT.jpg" Aspect="AspectFit" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill"></Image>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

**HomepageViewModel.cs:
*AppTappedCommand* is set correctly**

```
    this.AppTappedCommand = new DelegateCommand<ScanApplication>((app) => OnGotoScanPage(app));
    this.Title = ApplicationResources.ApplicationTitleCaption;

    public async void OnGotoScanPage(ScanApplication app)
    {
        NavigationParameters parameters = new NavigationParameters();
        parameters.Add(Constants.Parameters.App, app.AppId);
        await this.NavigationService.NavigateAsync($"{nameof(ScanPage)}", parameters);
    }
```

**ScanningApp.xaml.cs:
After Clicking the button *TappedCommand* is null.**

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty TappedCommandProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TappedCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(ScanningApp), default(ICommand), Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.OneWay);
    public ICommand TappedCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return (ICommand)GetValue(TappedCommandProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TappedCommandProperty, value);
        }
    }
    
    public static readonly BindableProperty TappedCommandParameterProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(TappedCommandParameter), typeof(object), typeof(ScanningApp), null, Xamarin.Forms.BindingMode.OneWay);
    public object TappedCommandParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValue(TappedCommandParameterProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TappedCommandParameterProperty, value);
        }
    }
    
    private bool OnExecuteTap()
    {
        img.Source = this.ImageSource;

        if (this.TappedCommand != null && this.TappedCommand.CanExecute(this.TappedCommandParameter))
        {
            this.TappedCommand.Execute(this.TappedCommandParameter);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

**ScanningApp.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="primetals.ScannerApp.Controls.ScanningApp"
             x:Name="self">
    <Grid Padding="1" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PrimetalsLightGrayColor}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
            </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="5*"></RowDefinition>
                <RowDefinition Height="1*" ></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Image x:Name="img" Grid.Row="0" Source="{Binding ImageSource, Source={x:Reference self}}" Aspect="AspectFit" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                   Margin="20"></Image>
            
            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference self}}" 
                   Margin="10,0,10,10"
                   FontSize="Medium" TextColor="{StaticResource PrimetalsAccentColor}"
                   VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"></Label>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>

</ContentView>
```

Originally this sourcecode worked (about one year ago) (but there may be problems with new packages in VS). I hope you can help me. Thanks a lot!

br

Comment: The binding could be not working for many reasons here we might wanna see the whole View, also the Command part of the VM, Also check details about self

Comment: I added the complete view and VM to my initial post. Regarding self I could not find any issues.

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there should be a `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` event handler in `ScanningApp.xaml.cs` from your code.

```
<TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"></TapGestureRecognizer>
```

So you could do like :

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        img.Source = this.ImageSource;
        if (this.TappedCommand != null && this.TappedCommand.CanExecute(this.TappedCommandParameter))
        {
            this.TappedCommand.Execute(this.TappedCommandParameter);
        }
    }
```